# Can't get GWT to work with SpringRoo

Tags: maven-2, gwt, spring-roo

---

**UPDATE #2:** The boys down at SpringRoo passed the buck over to the boys over at Google. See the ticket [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5351). It was upgraded to critical priority as well.

---

**UPDATE:** I've logged a bug on the SpringRoo Issue Tracker. It looks like the boys are taking this seriously. They've upgraded the priority from minor to critical. See the issue [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1482?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel).

---

Hi everyone,

I was able to get GWT to work with SpringRoo following the mini-tutorial on the SpringRoo page here: http://www.springsource.org/roo/start

I then decided to try their other tutorial here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html

After completing Step 6, I decided to try it out with GWT. I thought it would be as simple as running the `gwt setup` command from the Roo shell, but it wasn't. When I ran the project, I noticed that the command would create files (as expected), then start undoing the files it created, and finally end off with an exception: `String index out of range: -1`.

Not knowing much about Roo and GWT, I ran the `mvn gwt:run` command anyway, just to see if it might work. Well, to no surprise, it didn't.

I found the following JIRA issue for the `mvn gwt:run` command, but it didn't work. I'm sure it won't work until the first issue is resolved http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-57

**ADDITION:** MGWT-57 says to try mvn clean gwt:run. I did and tried running mvn gwt:run afterward to no avail -- same error message. MGWT-57 also says to move some nodes around though I must admit I have no clue what nodes they are referring to. I did, however, search for `gwt-maven-plugin` as well as the node `runTarget` as they were in the error message, but they were no where to be found in my pom.xml. I thought that to be strange, and deduced it's probably because of the first issue when running `gwt setup`.

I'm having a hard time finding anything for the first issue, running the `gwt setup` command in the Roo shell, which is why I'm here.

Any ideas?

I have included the output from the two commands below.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Output of the `gwt setup` command:

```
Managed ROOT/pom.xml
Managed ROOT/pom.xml [Added dependency com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:2.1-SNAPSHOT]
Managed ROOT/pom.xml [Added dependency com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.1-SNAPSHOT]
Managed ROOT/pom.xml [Added dependency org.json:json:20090211]
Managed ROOT/pom.xml
Managed SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/web.xml
Managed SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/ApplicationScaffold.gwt.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/ApplicationCommon.gwt.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/ApplicationMobileScaffold.gwt.xml
... MORE ...
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/scaffold/ScaffoldShell.java
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/scaffold/gwtLogo.png
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/scaffold
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/request
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/ApplicationMobileScaffold.gwt.xml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/ApplicationCommon.gwt.xml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt/ApplicationScaffold.gwt.xml
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/springsource/roo/pizzashop/gwt
Undo manage SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml
Undo manage SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/web.xml
Undo manage ROOT/pom.xml
String index out of range: -1
```

Here's the output from the mvn gwt:run command:

```
$ mvn gwt:run -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'gwt'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pizzashop
[INFO]    task-segment: [gwt:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing gwt:run
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'gwt:run'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'gwt-maven-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <runTarget>VALUE</runTarget>
</configuration>

-OR-

on the command line, specify: '-DrunTarget=VALUE'

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error configuring: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin. Reason: Invalid or missing parameters: [Mojo parameter [name: 'runTarget'; alias: 'null']] for mojo: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.2:run
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:723)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: Error configuring: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin. Reason: Invalid or missing parameters: [Mojo parameter [name: 'runTarget'; alias: 'null']] for mojo: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.2:run
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredParameters(DefaultPluginManager.java:1117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:722)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 03 12:14:32 CDT 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/116M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**ADDITION**
As per request, here is my pom.xml. I apologize in advance, I have no idea which sections are relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springsource.roo.pizzashop</groupId>
    <artifactId>pizzashop</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pizzashop</name>
    <properties>
        <roo.version>1.1.0.M3</roo.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.6.10.M1</aspectj.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repo</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <name>JBoss Repo</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
            <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
            <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ROO dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${roo.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
                <!--
                    <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration>
                -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>  <!--  Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.2.v20100523</version>
                <configuration>
                   <webAppConfig>
                     <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                   </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Without your pom.xml (at least the relevant sections), it seemes hard to say anything. What part of MGWT-57 didn't work for you?

Comment: I'll add it to my original post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure which sections are relevant, so I posted the whole thing. I also added my results of trying MGWT-57.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the pizzahop with GWT a few days ago and it worked. Tested on a linux machine with java 1.6, maven 2.2. This may not help a lot but at least it is somehow working.If you like a can upload a zip file with the whole project which you may can run with gwt.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here. I'm new to SpringRoo and just trying to create two simple entities with some fields, but the gwt:run command keeps failing. Thanks for posting it (this is only relevant information I found) and reporting the issue.

My error log:

```
C:\temp\test>mvn gwt:run -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (default-cli) @ test >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (default) @ test ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.2:resources (default-resources) @ test ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (default-cli) @ test <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.422s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 18 21:26:30 CET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/14M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (def
ault-cli) on project test: The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo
:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (default-cli) on project test: The p
arameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run are
missing or invalid
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:445)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: The parameters 'run
Target' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run are missing or inv
alid
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePl
uginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:514)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfigu
redMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:467)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:195)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParamete
rException
```

Comment: Please do not post an answer unless it actually will answer the question.